# In Ubuntu 17.10, how do I delete existing mobile broadband connections?

Tags: 17.10, mobile-broadband

I cannot figure out how to delete the existing mobile broadband collections in Ubuntu 17.10. Can someone help?

In the GUI it is clear how to add and how to edit, but cannot find the delete option.

Comment: Those are stored on disk with the connection name as part of the file name. So you could drop to a terminal, locate one and remove it ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can launch another GUI connection manager by running the following command in Terminal

```
nm-connection-editor
```

Once the window appears, select the connection you want to remove and delete it by clicking on the "**-**" (minus) symbol.

Answer (score 4):

Or from the command line:

```
nmcli connection show
```

Find your broadband entry on the list, let's say it's "My Broadband", then delete it with this:

```
nmcli connection delete "My Broadband"
```